# Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist. x Columns `Q2`, `Q2`, `Q2`, `Q2`, `Q2`, etc. don't exist. in R

Tags: r

Can someone explain why I have the error saying I am trying to submit columns that don't exist when I am actually not trying to submit that column?

The error is this one:

> Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
> x Columns `Q2`, `Q2`, `Q2`, `Q2`, `Q2`, etc. don't exist.

But 'Q2' are values of a column I have created before and not variable names.

Below the details:

```
#load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(stargazer)
library(lubridate)
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

#Reading data
raw_data <- read.csv(file= "data/nyc_open_data_vehicle_collisions.csv")

#Inspecting the structure of the dataset
names(raw_data)
tail(raw_data, 3)
str(raw_data)

Sys.getlocale()
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "English")
table(raw_data$CRASH.DATE)

table(raw_data$CRASH.DATE)
#Giving it format as date to CRASH.DATE
raw_data$CRASH.DATE <- as.Date(raw_data$CRASH.DATE, format="%m/ %d/ %Y")
#Creating a new variable that identify the quarter of the crash
raw_data$CRASH.QUARTER <- quarters(raw_data$CRASH.DATE)
#Creating a new variable that identify the year of the crash
raw_data$CRASH.YEAR <- year(raw_data$CRASH.DATE)
#cheking if it make sense
head(raw_data[,c("CRASH.DATE","CRASH.QUARTER", "CRASH.YEAR")],10)


#Creating new dataset:
#panel_df <- raw_data`enter code here`
panel_df <- raw_data %>%
  select (ZIPCODE <- raw_data$ZIP.CODE,
          YEAR <- raw_data$CRASH.YEAR,
          QUARTER <- raw_data$CRASH.QUARTER,
          NUMBER.OF.CRASHES <- "1",
          TOTAL.NUMBER.OF.PERSONS.INJURIED <- raw_data$NUMBER.OF.PERSON.INJURED,
          TOTAL.NUMBER.OF.PERSONS.KILLED <- raw_data$NUMBER.OF.PERSON.KILLED,
          NUMBER.OF.CRASHES.WITH.INJURIES <- ifelse(raw_data$NUMBER.OF.PERSONS.INJURIED > "0" , 1, 0),
          NUMBER.OF.PERDESTRIANS.INJURED <- raw_data$NUMBER.OF.PEDESTRIANS.INJURED,
          NUMBER.OF.PEDESTRIANS.KILLED <- raw_data$NUMBER.OF.PEDESTRIANS.KILLED,
          NUMBER.OF.CYCLIST.INJURED <- raw_data$NUMBER.OF.CYCLIST.INJURED,
          NUMBER.OF.CYCLIST.KILLED <- raw_data$NUMBER.OF.CYCLIST.KILLED,
          NUMBER.OF.MOTORIST.INJURED <- raw_data$NUMBER.OF.MOTORIST.INJURED,
          NUMBER.OF.MOTORIST.KILLED <- raw_data$NUMBER.OF.MOTORIST.KILLED)
```

Answer (score 1):

In which line does the error occur?

A few things might help,

- make the "<-" in the select statement "="
- You don't need to specify the data again after the `raw_data %>%`, e.g. drop the
  "raw_data$"s for readability
- "1" is a character, whereas 1 is a numeric.  Probably you want one (1)
  crash

You should get something like:

```
panel_df <- raw_data %>%
  select(ZIPCODE = ZIP.CODE,
          YEAR = CRASH.YEAR,
          QUARTER = CRASH.QUARTER,
          NUMBER.OF.CRASHES = 1,
...
```

Rerun your code, and see if you get the error.

Although not wrong, having such long variable names ("Number.of.motorist.injured") quickly becomes a pain to type and makes the statements long and so difficult to read.  Shorter is usually easier to code, something like "mot_inj".